# Android using httpclient and httpurlconnection to support all versions

Tags: java, android, http

I am creating an android app which will support `API level 8 (Froyo)` to `API LEVEL 19 (kitkat)`

Now the problem for me is that android uses majorly two http clients for HTTP requests:

1. Apache HTTP client (Which is good for eclair and froyo).
2. HttpURLConnection  ( Best for Gingerbread And Better).

So I thought about using both by detecting the version of the android

```
if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) <= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
{
        //use Apache Http client
}
else
{
       //use HttpURLconnection
}
```

The data i will be requesting will be some string and images. like list of names with images right to them. and all this will be done with in asynctask class.

Is this approach is correct for my requirement ? OR is there any other better solution available in android.

Comment: WOW you are the same guy who recommended it. AND a BIG YES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android **Volley library** handle this situation (**httpclient and httpurlconnection**) for you,and by default all the volley network calls works asynchronously, so we don’t have to worry about using `asynctask` also.

Volley comes with lot of features. Some of them are

1. Request queuing and prioritization
2. Effective request cache and memory management
3. Extensibility and customization of the library to our needs
4. Cancelling the requests

For more info see this [Android working with Volley Library](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this library [HTTP-Request](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request) and to forget about the compatibilities in addition to greatly facilitate the work of the HTTP requests.

For more info see this [More info](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request/blob/master/README.md)